# Best way to find values not in two lists c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists which I need to compare (carOptions and custOptions).
Both of these lists are in my Customer class like below:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    //other props removed for brevity
    public List<OptionDTO> SelectedCarOptions { get; set; }
    public List<OptionDTO> SelectedCustomerOptions { get; set; }
} 

        var existingData = _myRepository.GetDataByCustomer(customerId, year);

        var existingCarOptions = existingData.Select(f => f.SelectedCarOptions);
        var existingCustomerOptions = existingData.Select(f => f.SelectedCustomerOptions);
```

existingData is an IEnumerable of CustomerDTO and then existingCarOptions and existingCustomerOptions is an `IEnumerable<List<OptionDTO>>`

In the method, I have a list of `IEnumerable<OptionDTO>` options that gets passed in.  I  then break this down into car or customer based on the Enum as below:

```
        var newCarOptions = options.Where(o => o.OptionTypeID == OptionType.CarOptions);
        var newCustomerOptions = options.Where(o => o.OptionTypeID == OptionType.CustomerOptions).ToList();
```

What I need to do is find which options are in one collection but no in the other.

I tried as below but getting an Error on the Except (I maybe need to create my own static method in that class) but I am not sure this is the best approach really?

```
        if (existingCarOptions.Count() != newCarOptions.Count())
        {
            //var test = newCarOptions.Except(existingCarOptions);
        }

        if (existingCustomerOptions.Count() != newCustomerOptions.Count())
        {
            //var test2 = newCustomerOptions.Except(existingCustomerOptions);
        }
```

Is it also quite a bit of code in the method - I could split it out into sperate methods if required but perhaps there is a simpler way I could achieve this?

Comment: What is the error you get on the `.Except()`?

Comment: Are you missing `using System.Linq` using directive?

Comment: What are the generic type arguments for `existingCarOptions` and `newCarOptions`

Comment: You state that, "In the method, I have a list of IEnumerable options that gets passed in". What is the `type` of `options`? Is it also an `OptionDTO`, or is it some other class (I'm guessing it's a *regular* `Option` class, if you have such a thing, which is why you are getting an error on the `.Except()` method. Can you confirm this? And state what exception you're getting on the `Except()` method?

Comment: You could use a left outer join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: you probably need to use `SelectMany` when retrieving the existing options `existingData.SelectMany(f => f.SelectedCarOptions);` and `existingData.SelectMany(f => f.SelectedCustomerOptions);`, if you want to use `Except`

Comment: Apologies Forgot to include the error and I'm not at my machine. I will get it included later but from memory it was that no override for Except was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `OptionDTO` has a property called `Id`, which uniquely identifies an option (you have to change the code accordingly if this is not the case), you may use `HashSet`s to quickly find unmatched `OptionsDTO`s, while keeping the overall time cost `O(n)` (where n is the max number of combined options).

Create the existing options sets:

```
var existingCarOptions = existingData.SelectMany(d => d.SelectedCarOptions).Select(o => o.Id);
var existingCustomerOptions = existingData.SelectMany(d => d.SelectedCustomerOptions).Select(o => o.Id);

var existingCarOptionsIds = new HashSet<int>(existingCarOptions);
var existingCustomerOptionsIds = new HashSet<int>(existingCustomerOptions );
```

Then you extract options missing in existing sets with:

```
var unmatchedCarOptions = newCarOptions.Where(o => !existingCarOptionsIds.Contains(o.Id));
var unmatchedCustomerOptions = newCustomerOptions.Where(o => !existingCustomerOptionsIds.Contains(o.Id));
```

Comment: Yes there is an Id property.  Ill give this a go

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two classes you can use `IEqualityComparer`

```
 public class OptionComparer : IEqualityComparer<OptionDTO>
    {
        public bool Equals(OptionDTO x, OptionDTO y)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) ||
                object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return x.OptionTypeID == y.OptionTypeID ;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(OptionDTO obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return obj.OptionTypeID.GetHashCode();
        }
```

With using this you can ıdentify that What is the concept of equality for these classes.

Now we can find different values..

```
 public List<OptionDTO>CalculateDiffBetweenLists(List<OptionDTO> left, List<OptionDTO> right){

     List<OptionDTO> optionDiff;


    optionDiff = left.Except(right, new OptionComparer ()).ToList();

    return optionDiff ;
}
```

Comment: Correct for the reference types you need, either type implement `IEquatable<T>` or need to pass `IEqualityComparer<T>`, idea remains to override `GetHashCode` and Equals `methods` for equality comparison